# Python webbrowser.open() fails on Debian

Tags: python, browser, debian

When i run webbrowser.open() method, as in

```
python -c "import webbrowser; webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.google.it')"
```

The command open me a tab in the correct browser (chromium) but load a local copy of the file, in this case `file:///var/tmp/kdecache-norby/krun/6225.0.` that contains html but obviusly doesn't work as a dynamic page.

It fails with a debian unstable with KDE 4.4.5, contrairly with my Ubuntu installation where it work as expected. Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about kfmclient used by webbrowser module in KDE context. It wrongly openes remote files as local, as explained in http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/TaskOpenURL